# Code should print post of particular user but it is printing post of all users

Tags: django

```
**MODELS.PY**

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accounts:login")

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255,unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode = True,unique = True)
    description = models.TextField(default = '')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name = "group")

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Group,self).save(*args,**kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs = {'slug':self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:single',kwargs = {'username':self.user.username,'pk':self.pk})

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['-created_at']

**Views.py**

class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'posts/user_post_list.html'

    def get_query_set(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.username = get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=self.request.user.username)
            return models.Post.objects.filter(user=self.username)
        else:
            raise Http404

**Html Code**
  <div class="col-md-4">
    {% for post in post_list %}
      <p> {{ post.user.username }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

This code should print post of particular user but it is printing post of  all users, something is wrong with this code but i am not getting it.I have tried some other combinations but that also not working.Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is `get_queryset`, not `get_queryset`. Furthermore there is no need to use this `self.username = ...` thing, just `return Post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem , thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should change this as below. You can filter Posts by `self.request.user` of inside `get_queryset` method.

```
class UserPosts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Post
    template_name = 'posts/user_post_list.html'

    def get_query_set(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)    # filter posts by current user
        else:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: What are you getting?